# emacs' linum mode in emacs 21

Tags: emacs

For my job, I HAVE to use CentOS 5 as a development machine. CentOS 5 only comes with emacs 21, and I don't want to compile from source or use an RPM not approved for this OS, so I'm stuck with emacs 21.

The trouble is, `(global-linum-mode 1)` doesn't work.

I've installed `linum.el` and `whitespace.el`. Whitespace works fine, and if I do  `M-x linum-mode`  it works. How come emacs can't automatically just turn `linum-mode` on from the `.emacs` file? Isn't there a way to do that? Every page I come across says, 'yes, by entering `(global-linum-mode t)`' into your `.emacs` file, but that doesn't work in emacs 21.

Ideas?

Comment: You could download a precompiled binary, or if you can somehow get a another machine, use a later version of emacs locally, and edit files on the development machine from a machine. I'm afraid I have no answer for the actual question though.

Comment: If the alternative was using Emacs 21 in 2012, compiling from source is definitely the way I would go. Or alternatively, if it's a feasible workaround and your machine is suitable, run a VM with a more recent OS and run Emacs 24 inside that (using your local X display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `define-globalized-minor-mode` with `easy-mmode-define-global-mode` in linum.el and try again.

Comment: I had to do some tinkering with it, but your answer did it! Further, your answer has shown me how to turn any minor mode into a global mode - one way for emacs > 22, and one way for emacs < 22. +1 and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers.  There are a number of line numbering implementations that date from before `linum.el` was made part of the standard emacs distribution.

In particular, `line-num.el` from the above page claims to be compatible with emacs 21.